# Is a multiplicative inverse a unit itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse

Previously I've viewed units and multiplicative inverses to be mutually exclusive objects, but since every unit has a multiplicative inverse, then surely that unit acts as a multiplicative inverse for the original multiplicative inverse? So is it valid to say that every multiplicative inverse is also a unit itself?

Comment: It sounds like you're touching on the fact that $(u^{-1})^{-1} = u$? So yes, $u^{-1}$ has an inverse.

Comment: If $u$ is a unit, then $u^{-1}$ is again a unit. Perhaps this is what you want to say. You should express yourself more clearly.

Comment: Unit, invertible, and "divisor of $1$" are all equivalent properties (in a commutative monoid).  (one usually says $u$ is *invertible*, not $u$ is a multiplicative inverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, an element of a ring is a unit if and only if it is a multiplicative inverse. Namely, $u$ is a unit if and only if it is the multiplicative inverse of its own multiplicative inverse $u^{-1}$.